# Using React's Material-UI Library with Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, material-ui

I am very interested to begin learning Angular 2.0 and TypeScript. I came across a beautiful Material Design Library [Material-UI](http://material-ui.com) and noticed that it has a TypeScript definition at [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/material-ui) (A definition repo).

How would one use this Library and definition file alongside Angular 2.0's Syntax?
I cannot seem to find a guide or blog post about these two together anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How would one use this Library and definition file alongside Angular 2.0's Syntax? I cannot seem to find a guide or blog post about these two together anywhere.

Angular 2.0 isn't ready yet. However if you want to use it with Angular 1.0 you can use this library : https://github.com/davidchang/ngReact to wrap *react* components and *consume them from angular*.

Check usage : https://github.com/davidchang/ngReact#usage

Comment: Thanks for your answer but surely there is a way to use the React components with Angular 2.0 as there is a Definition file available. I'm sure you can understand that "Using Angular 1.0" is not really a valid answer as the whole point of this exercise it to become familiar with Angular 2.0.